# ASP.NET Web Service very slow when [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

Tags: asp.net, web-services, session

I have created a ASMX Web Service which does some Active Directory stuff behind the scene.

As I wish to retain certain information within Web Services under user session, I have decided to put  `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` and start using `Session` variables.

However, when I turn that option on, the return time from app -> web service -> app has became ridiculously long. (about a minute or more).

If I remove `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]`, it is fairly fast.

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Did you set up a session server ?

Comment: Maybe a connection time out to the session data?

Comment: @Steve B: I thought ASP.NET server box looks after the sessions, as long as it is enabled?

Comment: @Aristos It is consecutively slow when I access the web service right afterwards

Comment: A session server is required when you are running multiple frontends that have to share sessions. Versus a single box where session store is in-memory. You can check if this is setup in the web config (looking for [sessionState key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible reasons:

1. Session state is stored out of process (state server/ SQL server) and getting/storing it taking a long time
2. You are making multiple concurrent requests (including service requests) under the same session. ASP.NET ensures that only one session-full (session read/write) request execute at a time and hence, multiple concurrent requests would queue up.

**EDIT** :
For #2, obvious solution is to avoid session state use - for example, can you put the relevant information into another store such as cache or database (expensive).

If you are only reading session state in web service then you may take advantage of read-only session state (see [IReadOnlySessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx)). Read-only session state allows concurrent read-only requests - read/write request will still block all other requests. Now, `EnableSession` from `WebMethod` attribute does not support this - it either provides no session or read/write session. So one of the workaround can be to implement your own handler implementing `IReadOnlySessionState` and then route asmx request to thi handler using a http-module and then switch the handler to default one later. Because your handler requires read-only session state, you will have the read-only session state - see this [forum post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1098574/1665773.aspx) where such http-module that switches the handler has been given.

Comment: If they are the reasons, how would I be able to fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the second one

Comment: @James, if #2 is the reason then you can see that by steady increase in the number of request queued. From client side, you will see progressive degradation as requests start piling up. For possible solution, see my edit in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Turns out it the delay wasn't coming from the sessions but an Invoke from DirectoryServices. When I turned the session off, it was causing some error but caught and didn't do anything so I thought it was smooth sailing. Cheers

Comment: But I will mark yours as answer as it is a sound response to me.

Comment: I stumbled upon this while I was trying to find a way to use read only session state for web services (.asmx). The link to the forum post is exactly what I needed - I used the sample code and just changed it to ignore anything other than .asmx files, and changed MyHttpHandler to inherit from IReadOnlySessionState instead of IRequiresSessionState and it works perfectly. Thanks!